# docker pull requested access to the resource is denied from hub.docker.com

Tags: docker

This sounds like a silly problem but I'm not able to pull anything from my own private DockerHub repos.

```
zsh: docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: my-username
Password: 
Login Succeeded

zsh: docker pull my-username/my-app:latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my-username/my-app, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I checked if I misspelt something or don't have the access rights. But even in Docker Desktop, I get the same error when trying to pull an image from the "Remote Repositories"-tab list within the "Images"-menu. When I navigate to the hub.docker.com page I'll see the image.

Havn't found any working solution on the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple reson is: **you have reached the limit of private repos**.

You might want to upgrade, switch to another provider or build your own local image repository.

I answer my own question, so anyone googeling around and trying to fix this issue can find this solution. I upgraded my plan to Docker Pro and continued using DockerHub without any issues.